# How to write loop for creating multiple variables in R

Tags: r

I have a data set in R called `data`, and in this data set I have more than 600 variables. Among these variables I have 94 variables called `data$sleep1,data$sleep2...data$sleep94`, and another 94 variables called `data$wakeup1,data$wakeup2...data$wakeup94`.

I want to create new variables, `data$total1-data$total94`, each of which is the sum of `sleep` and `wakeup` for the same day.

For example, `data$total64 <-data$sleep64 + data$wakeup64`,`data$total94<-data$sleep94+data$wakeup94`.

Without a loop, I need to write this code 94 times. I hope someone could give me some tips on this. It doesn't have to be a loop, but an easier way to do this.

FYI, every variables are numeric and have about 30% missing values. The missing are random, it could be anywhere. missing value is a blank but not 0.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend storing your data in long form. To do this, use `melt`. I'll use `data.table`.

Sample data:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(102943)
x <- setnames(as.data.table(matrix(runif(1880), nrow = 10)),
              paste0(c("sleep", "wakeup"), rep(1:94, 2)))[ , id := 1:.N]
```

Melt:

```
long_data <- 
  melt(x, id.vars = "id", 
       measure.vars = list(paste0("sleep", 1:94),
                           paste0("wakeup", 1:94)))

#rename the output to look more familiar
#**note: this syntax only works in the development version;
#        to install, follow instructions
#        here: https://github.com/jtilly/install_github
#        to install from https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table
#        (or, read ?setnames and figure out how to make the old version work)
setnames(long_data, -1L, c("day", "sleep", "wakeup"))
```

I hope you'll find it's much easier to work with the data in this form.

For example, your problem is now simple:

```
long_data[ , total := sleep + wakeup]
```

Answer (score 1):

We could do this without a loop.  Assuming that the columns are arranged in the sequence mentioned, we subset the 'sleep' columns and 'wakeup' columns separately using `grep` and then add the datasets together.

```
sleepDat <- data[grep('sleep', names(data))]
wakeDat <- data[grep('wakeup', names(data))]
nm1 <- paste0('total', 1:94)
data[nm1] <- sleepDat+wakeDat
```

If there are missing values and they are `NA`, we can `replace` the `NA` values with 0 and then add it together as before.

```
data[nm1] <- replace(sleepDat, is.na(sleepDat), 0) +
              replace(wakeDat, is.na(wakeDat), 0)
```

---

If the missing value is `''`, then the columns would be either `factor` or `character` class (not clear from the OP's post).  In that case, we may need to convert the dataset to `numeric` class so that the `''` will be automatically converted to `NA`

```
 sleepDat[] <- lapply(sleepDat, function(x) 
                      as.numeric(as.character(x)))
 wakeDat[] <- lapply(wakeDat, function(x) 
                     as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

and then proceed as before.

NOTE: If the columns are `character`, just omit the `as.character` step and use only `as.numeric`.

Comment: not clear that we replace `NA` with 0. See OP's last sentence.

Comment: @MichaelChirico  Thanks I updated with `''` as the possible missing value.

Comment: sorry, i meant that perhaps OP wants the output to _stay_ `NA`